# Why does pagespeed throw different performance scores on different browsers?

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, web-performance, core-web-vitals

I'm testing my site on PSI and see varying results on Edge vs Chrome (both are on incognito).

This difference could be based on other factors - which I haven't been able to determine. But for now, it *seems* to be different based on which browser I test this in.

That doesn't make sense to me, as the browser should not affect PSI scores.

```json
Browser: "Edge"
Performance score: 37
CLS: 0.121
```

[image]

[image]

```json
Browser: "Chrome"
Performance score: 65
CLS: 0.061
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser you're running does not affect PSI scores (the tests are run on a server, not on your machine), but PSI scores can vary from run to run, see this doc for a list of reasons why: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/variability.md